# How to correctly document that a method parameter should be a class name that implements a certain interface?

Tags: php, phpdoc

I'm using PHPDoc. I've got a method that accepts a string parameter. That string should be the name of a class that implements a certain interface, say, `IMyInterface`.

Should I do:

```
/**
 * @param string $class_name
 */
public function myMethod($class_name) {}
```

or

```
/**
 * @param IMyInterface $class_name
 */
public function myMethod($class_name) {}
```

I'm guessing that since classes and interfaces aren't first class in PHP, it's probably the latter. But something seems wrong about both options.

Comment: Don't be shy, write a full line of comment: $class_name is a  class  that implements...

Comment: Oh yeah, definitely not against that. But still, there is a "standard", and I just don't understand the docs of that standard, unfortunately. I want to know what is "correct" for the _Type_ field.

Answer (score 2):

I used ApiGen for a project I did a while back and I found it best to use the class name as it created linking within the documentation to the pages for those particular classes.  I haven't used PHPDoc, but perhaps it has similar functionality and make your documentation a little more accessible.

```
/**
* Constructor function.
*
* Creates a new user object with data provided.
*
* @return void
* @param mixed An array or object of user information to be read in.
* @param Permissions An instance of a Permissions object to associate with the user.
*/
public function __construct($data,$perms) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your use case, "string" is correct, because you are telling the reader exactly what kind of datatype to pass in.  If a user actually tried passing a concrete class instance of an IMyInterface implementer, your code is no doubt going to choke.

If your method is only built to accept a certain list of strings that represent a list of usable interfaces, then I'd suggest saying this outright in the method's long description, not in the one parameter's description.  I would also utilize the @see tags to provide links to the docs of all the interfaces this method is built to accept.  That way, your @param tag truly tells the reader "dude, I gotta have a string", your method description explains how the method will take that string and correlate it to a defined interface, and the @see tags will help the reader jump directly to any/all of the interfaces themselves.

Regarding IDE autocompletion, some IDEs can interpret "/** @var IMyInterface $localMethodVar */" inside your method code, and would then provide autocompletion on $localMethodVar as if it were a defined instance of IMyInterface.

Comment: What about @params that require objects? Do I use the class name?

Comment: Yes, when the parameter wants a particular object instance of a certain class, the datatype is that class name.